# Odd behaviour of listed pages in paginator

Tags: discussion, pagination

Does anyboy else find the Stack Exchange paginator (page selector) strange behaviour?

[image: Pagination examples]

It's ok at start, until...

- Case 4., why there is no [6], as it looks like, this paginator shows two pages before, and two after.
- Case 5., [2] is hidden behind [...], why you should hide only one number?
- Case 6., same as in case 5., [97659] is hidden with [...].
- Case 7., here is like it should be (not like in case 4.), two
  pages before current.

The thing is, I don't like that dynamic width (not speaking about next/prev dissapearing) of paginator and odd behaviour (cases 4., 5. and 6.).

(See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496742/page-selector-paginator-differences).)